# How the fix damaged subfloor over vent?

Tags: repair, flooring, subfloor

1946 house with all the wonders of years of questionable home renos, of which I am the latest in line. When I moved in I pulled the carpets for the lovely hardwood beneath but the carpet hid cracked hardwood and a damaged subfloor. I intend to refinish the floor in spring but the subfloor itself is cracked and upon further inspection I’m not sure how to reinforce it as there is a duct that runs right under in that section. Any tips or tricks would be much appreciated. I don’t have the finances right not to redo the duct work and frankly if I did I’d rewire the house instead.

Pictures of damage for context:

[image: close up re sf and duct]

[hardwood and sf damage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlYA8.jpg)

[image: proximity to wall vent]

[image]

Comment: Is there room to slide any boards between the subfloor and duct to bridge the gap(s)?

Comment: Is the floor springy there? Does stepping on it make it sag? If not, you _may_ not have to fix it. If you do want/need to fix, I believe you'd probably have to pull the trim off the wall, then remove enough flooring to pull those diagonal subfloor boards out and replace them. That'll mean removing a lot of flooring to even get one subfloor board out.

Comment: The direction of the opening and the thickness of the hardwood, quite likely no repair is necessary.  The hardwood should cover that small opening with no trouble.  Unless there are other problems than just that opening, just fix the hardwood.

Comment: Agreeing very much with @crip659. The gap between the subfloor boards isn't, in and of itself, reason to go "fixing" things. It may have been built that way.

Comment: Unfortunately the subfloor is springy as hell, and I believe the downward angle is not mirrored by the subfloor on either side of the damage. The issue isn’t so great as it’s not a high traffic area per se but if I need to replace the floor pieces anyway when I refinish I would rather reinforce it or fix it

Comment: Springy subfloor will probably be fix from below.  Check the joists and see if any need adjustment/strengthening.  This probably might be a new question about the subfloor.

Comment: That seem like information that should be in your _question_, not down here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider that an issue. The solid hardwood flooring is more than capable of spanning that small gap. In fact, many subfloors of the era had gaps that large left deliberately out of frugality.

However, you *could* repair it by slipping a scab through using creative means and screwing it to the underside through the adjacent subfloor, then filling the slot with wood. I'd use construction adhesive at all points for extra stability. You could cut a larger opening to facilitate this, but avoid cutting out anything that provides critical support. Make the scab as large as the workspace allows.

Related questions:

- [How to repair/replace old tongue and groove plank subfloor in bathroom?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157845/how-to-repair-replace-old-tongue-and-groove-plank-subfloor-in-bathroom)
- [How do I repair my partially rotted subfloor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/161663/how-do-i-repair-my-partially-rotted-subfloor)
- [Wall plate and subfloor repair in bathroom](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195499/wall-plate-and-subfloor-repair-in-bathroom)
- [How do I fix/cover this hole in my kitchen subfloor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/256629/how-do-i-fix-cover-this-hole-in-my-kitchen-subfloor)